# How to connect an NXT brick to the LEGO programmer application on an iPad?

Tags: ev3, nxt, bluetooth, ios

Can you connect a NXT brick to an iPad via either USB cable or Bluetooth? For me neither seem to work even though the EV3 brick (and the LEGO programmer application) should be backwards compatible.

I can connect the NXT to the iPad: both are displayed by the other device as connected. But in the LEGO programmer, the NXT does not show up as an available brick.

I have also tried to connect with 2 USB cables that have a male to male  connection in between. There seems to be no option for that at all in the LEGO programmer.

Does anyone have another idea how I can get these two devices to communicate and download files?

Answer (score 1):

The NXT only works with the EV3 desktop software (for Windows and Mac) and only via USB.

I'm not aware of any way to program NXT using an iPad (or Android, or Chromebook).